# The output video is not same as the original video Open CV

Tags: python, opencv

I am having an issue when reading a video in open cv. When I run the output, it is not showing the whole video. It is like a zoomed video. Output video is not same as original video. How to show the whole video? I am a newbie in python and open cv. Below is the screenshot of the output.
[image]

And below is the real image of the video
[image]

```
vidCap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

 while (True):
    success, img = vidCap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, bw = cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    bw = imclearborder(bw)
    RemoveTop(bw, round(bw.shape[0] * 0.6))
    RemoveTriangle(bw)
    bw = bwareaopen(bw, 700)
    blueMask = img.copy()
    blueMask[:, :] = (255, 0, 0)
    cv2.copyTo(blueMask, bw, img)
    cv2.imshow('Output', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
vidCap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect the output to show the whole video same as the original video

Comment: maybe it is because of the imclearborder or RemoveTop stuff in. your code? What does this do?

Comment: Write a minimal application that just shows the video. You have a lot of calls in the code that don't need to be there if you are trying to fix this simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess your video resolution is bigger than your screen resolution.

First image is from opencv window, I believe second image is not generated by opencv, but by a video player that shrink the video to fit in your screen.

You should resize your img with this untested code:

```
imgToShow = cv.resize(img, img.size()/2)
cv2.imshow(imgToShow)
```

I use opencv with C++, not with Python, so please check the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
scale_percent = 60  # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow('Output', resized)
```